# How can I extract data from an excel file like this using python and pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I extract data from an excel file like this using python and pandas? It has got multiple tables at different positions.
Here is the structure of the table
[image]

I want the tables as different dataframes. For this file I want these three tables as three different dataframes from which I can create separate excel or csv files. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a csv file

```
https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/6409-saving-an-excel-file-as-a-csv-file?lang=en_US
```

Then you use an IDE like VSCode, interpreter like python and packages like pandas to convert the csv file back into a table.
Below is a simple python code to convert the csv into table

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame("/path/to/csv/file")
```

Comment: I can read it. What I want is I want to be able to detect these three tables as separate dataframes which I can export to csv or excel.

Comment: You can separate these 3 tables into 3 different worksheets first.